# Render and return inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, render

In my code, I call a function `showUsers`. This function displays all the users in a styled box. For now, the `numberOfUsers` passed into it is 1, as confirmed by console.logs as well.

So the loop should only runs once. However, all these console.logs are repeated twice. The output values remain the same.  Why is this so?

```
         console.log('Number of Users in Loop: ', numberOfUsers);
         console.log('Whats the Id', userId);
         console.log('UserName', userName);
         console.log('i: ', i);
```

Code:

```
export const Page: React.FunctionComponent<PageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendEmailPage,
}) => {
  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    email: '',
  };

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UsersLazyQueryHookResult>('');
  const [numberOfUsers, setNumberOfUsers] = useState('');
  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserData(userData);
    setNumberOfUsers(numberOfUsers);
  }, [userData, numberOfUsers]);


  const showAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert('Friend Added');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAddFriendEmailPage) return;
    initialValues.email = '';
  }, [showAddFriendEmailPage]);

  const _onLoadUserError = React.useCallback((error: ApolloError) => {
    setErrorMessage(error.message);
    Alert.alert('Unable to Add Friend');
  }, []);

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
      called: isMutationCalled,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation({
    onCompleted: (data: CreateUserRelationMutationResult) => {
      showAlert();
    },
  });

   const showUsers = React.useCallback(
     (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
       for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
        console.log('Number of Users in Loop: ', numberOfUsers);
         const userId = data.users.nodes[i].id;
         const userName = ((data.users.nodes[i].firstName).concat(' ')).concat(data.users.nodes[i].lastName);
         console.log('Whats the Id', userId);
         console.log('UserName', userName);
         console.log('Loop');
         return(
           <View style={styles.friends}>
             <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>{userName}</Text>
             </View>
           </View>
         )
       }      
     },
     [createUserRelationMutation],
   );

  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      console.log('Whats the Id', id);
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          setUserData(data);
          setNumberOfUsers(data.users.nodes.length);
          //showUsers(data, Number(numberOfUsers));
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
  );

  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.email },
        },
      });
      values.email = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showAddFriendEmailPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="email"
                        render={msg => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        rounded
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Add Friend </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
            {showUsers(userData, Number(numberOfUsers))}
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
export const Page: React.FunctionComponent<PageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendEmailPage,
}) => {
  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    email: '',
  };

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UsersLazyQueryHookResult>('');
  const [numberOfUsers, setNumberOfUsers] = useState('');

  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

   const showUsers = React.useCallback(
     (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
      if (data){
       for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
         console.log('Number of Users in Loop: ', numberOfUsers);
         const userId = data.users.nodes[i].id;
         const userName = data.users.nodes[i].firstName
           .concat(' ')
           .concat(data.users.nodes[i].lastName);
         return (
           <View style={styles.friends}>
             <View style={styles.item}>
               <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
               <View style={styles.addButtonContainer}>
                 <Button
                   onPress={() => {
                     addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[i].id));
                     setIsSubmitted(false);
                   }}>
                 </Button>
               </View>
             </View>
           </View>
         );
       }}
     },
     [createUserRelationMutation, userData, numberOfUsers],
   );

  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      console.log('Whats the Id', id);
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          setUserData(data);
          setNumberOfUsers(data.users.nodes.length);
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
  );



  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(

    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      setIsSubmitted(true);
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.email },
        },
      });
      values.email = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
  );


  if (!addingFriendLoading && isMutationCalled) {
    if (addingFriendError) {
      setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
      Alert.alert('Unable to Add Friend');
    }
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showAddFriendEmailPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View style={styles.searchTopTextContainer}>
              <Text
                style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}
                onPress={() => {
                 toggleShowPage()
                  setIsSubmitted(false);
                  setUserData(null);
              }}
              >
                Cancel
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchTopMiddleText}>
                Add Friend by Email
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}>Done</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="email"
                        render={msg => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        rounded
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Search </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
            {isSubmitted && showUsers(userData, Number(numberOfUsers))}    
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: But i can see 2 calls to `showUsers` 1 from render , 2nd from `getFriendId `

Comment: Oops, I already fixed that. Before that I was getting 3 logs. Now after removing the one from getFriendId, I still get 2 logs. @VivekDoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also calling `setUserData` from `getFriendId`, so it will update `userData`

```
const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    ....
    setUserData(data);
```

So it will invoke `render` and `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUserData(userData);
    setNumberOfUsers(numberOfUsers);
}, [userData, numberOfUsers]);
```

You can comment out `useEffect` and check no of `console.log`

Comment: Hmm but then the userData & numberOfUsers won't be updated properly on every query. How else can I automatically update ```userData```every time there's new data?

Comment: If I remove the useEffect, I get only one log but I am not sure if it correctly updates data or not because after hitting the submit button once, I am unable to submit the form again

Comment: It's due to `render`, your dom is rendering 2 times , `setNumberOfUsers` this will also rerender the dom, 1) via `setUserData` , this will force to useEffect 2) via `setNumberOfUsers`, this will also render the dom due to `useEffect`, as they both are setting up state

Comment: Do you have any ideas about the form resetting issue?

Comment: @a125, no idea, but I can help you if you create a demo over stackblitz or codesandbox